# Windows 10 does not allow me to extend the PATH

Tags: windows-10, path, control-panel

Crossposting note: I have already opened a discussion on this topic on [the Windows 10 forum](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/134488-changing-path-does-not-take-effect.html#post1651132), but did not get any useful answer.

I want to extend the PATH to include also my directory C:\WBIN. I modified it using the control center for environment variables, as seen in this [screenshot](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/236883d1560262730t-changing-path-does-not-take-effect-capture_20190611_161205.jpg), but when I open a [command line console](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/236885d1560263655t-changing-path-does-not-take-effect-capture_20190611_163451.jpg), my directory is not in the path.

Revising the settings, I [still can see my path](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/general-support/236884d1560263568t-changing-path-does-not-take-effect-capture_20190611_163254.jpg) entered. Why doesn't this change take effect, when I start a new process?

Comment: AFAIK, Windows reads in the PATH variables at boot. Have you tried re-booting?

Comment: Of course! However, this should not be necessary. A change in the environment variables should affect every process created afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your uptime from here... Also, should != does.

Comment: I would surprised if *this* behaviour of Windows changed. In the previous versions (XT, 7, 8) which I had used, a reboot was not necessary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, PATH changes are applied on login. You have to log out and log in, full reboot is not necessary. This was the case since forever, including XP, 7 and 8.

Comment: I find it also odd that the PATH displayed on my command console looks completely different from the one I see in the control center. If you look at the screenshots: It is not just that what I had added is missing; it contains a lot of other components which I don't see in the control center. I wonder how Windows 10 is putting together the PATH.

Comment: The PATH is made up of both user variables, and system variables. Use the Environment Variables tool under System Properties > Advanced to see what each of them contains.

Comment: @gronstaj: While I don't remember ever having logged out instead of restarting programs to reflect changes in the environment, your comment made me search for this problem now using different keywords, and thanks to this, I came accross a posting which provided a solution. See my own answer below.

Comment: @MichaelFrank : I can see that there are two sets of variables, both containing a PATH. I can only edit the ones in the "user" section, not the ones labelled "system". So this explains where I get that mixed path from.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I found a discussion about the same problem [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting), which contained a solution which actually worked:

Instead of updating my PATH using the control center (which seems to be broken somehow), I opened a command line window and used the command

```
SETX PATH="%PATH%";C:\WBIN
```

After this, no logout required: Every new process sees this PATH, **and** the settings survive a reboot.

Comment: How is the "control center" broken?

Comment: In that AFIK we are supposed to be able to set environment variables through the control center too. At least in previous Windows versions, this worked well.

Comment: As we explained in comments, we are. It just requires a relogin and it always did, at least since Windows 2000 if my memory serves well. I suppose it was always like this (probably inspired by Unix?).

Comment: Well, but I *did* a relogin, and the PATH was not changed. Only after I set it with `setx`, the change had an effect. And on my previous system (Win7), I often fiddled with the path, either manually, or by installing programs where the installer put their directory into the path, and a relogin was never needed. Maybe the initial environment settings are stored in the registry, and every new process gets its environment from there? Of course it's just a guess, but with this architecture, a relogin would not make sense.

Comment: @gronostaj : Indeed, the registry seems to be used for the environment. See [this guide](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/113/windows-10-set-path.html). But you seem to be right: In the last sentence, the page also says that you even have to reboot, which seems to be a weird requirement to me.